# How to not display a link outside of a div element?

Tags: html, css, overflow

HTML codes:

```
<p>texts and a link: <a href="https://www.apple.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">https://www.apple.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
```

CSS codes:

```
p {
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
}
```

See codes demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9j4pT

From code demo, you see the link is displayed outside of red paragraph element. I hope the link can be displayed inside of red paragraph element. Is there a solution? Does HTML5 have a solution to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you want to close your p tag with `</p>`

Then you want word-wrap:

```
p {
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sean and user2019515.

Comment: If that's what you were looking for can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the overflow to hidden.

```
p {
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the result you're look for.

If you want the **p width** to stay the same, use:

```
p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

If you want the **a width** to stay the same, use:

```
p {
   /*remove width: 100px;*/
   display: inline-block;
}
```